# Update Django postgresql database in Digital Ocean Droplet?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, digital-ocean

This question might be out of this site's context, so please redirect me to the right site if that's the case. Anyway, I have Django installed in a Digital Ocean Droplet, I moved my apps with FileZilla to the server, setup the correct static folders and everything is working fine except from the database. Now, I have created a postgresql database on my computer and I've added some data, but I have no idea how I can move them to the server database. I don't know much about databases, I'm not ever sure where my database is located. Is there any way of automatic database deployment, or perhaps a way to find where it is and move it with FileZilla to the server?

Comment: pg_dump on your local dev server and pg_restore on the remote (both commands are well explained in the postgresql docs)

Comment: So it basically copies data from one db to the other?

Comment: Well no, you will have to copy the file that's produced by pg_dump youself :)

Comment: But actually it's possible to chain pg_dump and pg_restore but let's leave such complicated methods until you get more familar with postgresql

Comment: Right, I'll check it out, thanks. But, are there any commands to find where the databases are?

Comment: You don't need to do this for dump and restore. If ou need it for another reason 'SHOW data_directory' in the psql console will show you.

Comment: OK, thank you! That should be enough for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SSH` to connect to your droplet, then proceed to `postgresql-server` installation. Look at the [install guides](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides) to get this done.

Your database will be located in your droplet, then you'll configure `Django settings.py` to connect to your local database at `127.0.0.1`.

You can have a look at this very good [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04) for Ubuntu on DigitalOcean.

All you have to do then is configuring the db for using with `Django` and migrating your app.

Django provides an easy way to export/import db data :

`python manage.py dumpdata` will generate an output, on Linux just redirect it `> fixture.json`. Do this on your offline installation.

Then, manage to put this file on your server, and load it with the following command : `python loaddata fixture`. That will work, as you don't forget to synchronize both database schemas with `migrations`.

Comment: I have already installed postgresql, I just don't know how to synchronize it with my offline database...

Comment: Thank you, that's great! But, edit your answer to output to something like fixture.json, I couldn't get your out.fixture to work. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :). Sorry, couldn't precisely remind file extension `load/dumpdata` was working with.